# recursive grep started at / hangs

Tags: debian, freebsd, grep

I have used following grep search pattern on multiple platforms:

```
grep -r -I -D skip 'string_to_match' /
```

For example on *FreeBSD 8.0*, *FreeBSD 6.4* and *Debian 6.0*(squeeze). Command does a recursive search starting from root directory, assumes that binary files do not have the 'string_to_match' and skips devices, sockets and named pipes. *FreeBSD 8.0* and *FreeBSD 6.4* use GNU grep version 2.5.1 and *Debian 6.0* uses GNU grep version 2.6.3. On *FreeBSD 6.4*, last information printed to stderr was **"grep: /dev/cuad0: Device busy"**. After this grep just idles as according to "top -m io -o total" the I/O usage of grep is nonexistent. Same behavior is true under *FreeBSD 8.0*, but last information sent to stderr is **"grep: /tmp/.wine-0: Permission denied"** on my installation. In case of Debian, last output to stderr is **"grep: /proc/sysrq-trigger: Input/output error"**. If I check the I/O usage of grep process under Debian, it is following:

```
root@Debian:~# iotop -bp 22439
Total DISK READ: 0.00 B/s | Total DISK WRITE: 0.00 B/s
  TID  PRIO  USER     DISK READ  DISK WRITE  SWAPIN      IO    COMMAND
22439 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % grep -r -I
-D skip 10.10.10.99 /
Total DISK READ: 0.00 B/s | Total DISK WRITE: 0.00 B/s
  TID  PRIO  USER     DISK READ  DISK WRITE  SWAPIN      IO    COMMAND
22439 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % grep -r -I
-D skip 10.10.10.99 /
Total DISK READ: 0.00 B/s | Total DISK WRITE: 0.00 B/s
  TID  PRIO  USER     DISK READ  DISK WRITE  SWAPIN      IO    COMMAND
22439 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % grep -r -I
-D skip 10.10.10.99 /
^Croot@Debian:~#
```

What might cause this? Is there a way to view which file *grep* is currently processing in case *lsof* is not present? I'm able to use *lsof* under Debian and looks like the problematic file name there is "0xc6b2c230 file struct, ty=0, op=0xc0d34120". I'm not sure what this is.. I'm not able to use *lsof* or *fstat* under FreeBSD.

PS: I know I could use *find* utility, but this is not the question.

Comment: With GNU `grep`, have you tried the `-H` option?

Comment: Whoever just downvoted, you should consider adding a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Linux, instead of `lsof` you can list the contents of `/proc/$(pgrep grep)/fd`. You should see a symlink for each open file descriptor for that process and it will point to the file that it corresponds to. Here is a sample of what this did for me:

```
$ ls -gG /proc/$(pgrep grep)/fd
total 0
lrwx------ 1 64 Oct 18 19:39 0 -> /dev/pts/2
lrwx------ 1 64 Oct 18 19:39 1 -> /dev/pts/2
lrwx------ 1 64 Oct 18 19:39 2 -> /dev/pts/2
lr-x------ 1 64 Oct 18 19:39 3 -> /usr/share/groff/1.18.1.4/font/devdvi/generate/texb.map
```

Comment: Unfortunately, looks like this is not possible under FreeBSD. I executed `grep -r -I -D skip 'string_to_match' /` under OpenSUSE 12.1 and there it got stuck to _/proc/kmsg_ file, which is a file used for holding messages generated by kernel.

Comment: `/proc/kmsg` is likley to always be a problem so you may want to consider the `-x` option. Other than that, isn't it possible to attach to the process with a debugger and figure out the file it is stuck on?